# One problematic route not testing properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, routes, capybara

I'm using rspec-rails, capybara with poltergeist (phantomjs) for testing. I'm using Sorcery for authentication gem.

I have only implemented the basic user model so far, and all my routes work except `signup_path`... I have no idea why this is the only route that seems to be broken. It DOES work perfectly fine if I visit it in my own browser at localhost:3000/register

Here's my test code as a sample

```
it "shows a valid signup path", js: true do
  visit signup_path
  page.should have_content("Sign Up")
end
```

I get this error:

```
expected there to be text "Sign Up" in 
"Internal Server Error undefined method `escape' for 
nil:NilClass WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2012-04-20) at 127.0.0.1:55402"
```

I can replace `signup_path` with any other route in my app. The test will fail, but at least it will say "can't find Sign Up in `<insert content of that page here>`". So even though the test fails I can blatantly see the content of that page right int he output of the test. For signup_path it's just straight up failing though, and I can't view the error myself because it works if I visit it in my own browser.

Here is my routes

```
 # User
  get 'register' => 'users#new', :as => 'signup'
  resources :users, :only => [:create, :edit, :update]

  # Session Authentication
  get 'login'  => 'sessions#new',     :as => 'login'
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
  resources :sessions, :except => [:new, :destroy]
```